# Why isn't my External Hard Drive getting backed up by Backblaze?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, online-backup, backblaze

My External Hard Drive (8 TB Seagate External Hard Drive mounted as disk letter F) isn't backed up. by Backblaze? See demo below. Why isn't it getting backed up?

I read https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217665398-Backing-up-External-Hard-Drives and it satisfies all the 5 requirements to be backed up:

1. Natively read/write accessible by the operating system. (NTFS formatted, and I use Microsoft Windows)
2. Directly connected to the computer via USB
3. Not a Time Machine backup volume (macOS only)
4. Not mounted as a 'removable storage device'
5. In working condition

[image]

I use Backblaze with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I'd ask Backblaze - but bear in mind it's on an unsupported OS, so they may not be interested.

Comment: @Tetsujin backblaze supports windows 7

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Microsoft doesn't, which means Backblaze and other developers have limited options for supporting the OS.

Comment: @music2myear I don't think this is that limiting for this kind of basic features

Comment: That's a lot of assumptions. What is a basic feature? What issues will the Dev experience as an OS is abandoned by its publisher?

Comment: @music2myear starting some upload is a basic feature.

Comment: Mounting a transient external drive for backups may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the "Backup now" button doesn't immediately back up any new drive selected for backup. It took my backblaze a few hours before starting to back up the external hard drive.

Comment: I think that the "Backup Now" button has no effect at all in your case, since you are using the "continuous backup" schedule. When a backed up external drive is unplugged, Backblaze takes always a significant amount of time before taking it into account again when re-plugged. I guess this is the same for any drive newly selected for backup. Moreover on your screen capture you already had 400MB of files in the backup queue, before any file of the new drive can be backed up.